Calculation of the number of invitations delivered
At a meeting of brokers, both men and women were present, with there being $13$ more men than women. Each man present handed out 1 business card to every other man and 3 business cards to each woman. Each woman present handed out $2$ business cards to each other woman and 3 business cards to each man. In total, $282$ cards were delivered more visitors for men than for women. Knowing that the number of men in the meeting is not a multiple of $19$, then this number is a multiple of
(Answer:$17$)
I try:
x= man:y = women
x = y+13
(I) card to man: $(x(x-1) + 3xy = x^2-x+3x(x-13) =\therefore 4x^2 - 40x$
(II) card to women:$3xy+{\color{red}2y}(y-1) = 3xy+2y^2-2y = 5x^2-93x+364 $
$(I)=(II)+282 \implies 4x^2-40x = 5x^2-93x+364 +282 \therefore \boxed{x = 34} \vee {x = 19}$
Now it worked

Why number of cards to women is $3xy + y(y - 1)$ and not $3xy + \color{red}{2}y(y-1)$?

@mihaild My mistake...Now it worked..thanks
